# Is there support for AddingNewEventHandler in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, event-handling

I don't see AddingNewEventHandler in System.ComponentModel and just wanted to double check with a support community before totally writing off it's use in a MonoTouch project of mine.

thanks,

-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for AddingNewEventHandler.